# Can i change Nginx variable client_max_body_size value from php.ini file?

Tags: linux, configuration, nginx, drupal-7

i dont have a write access to /etc/nginx/nginx.conf file and i can see that client_max_body_size is set to a lower value than i need. Before i can contact the server administrator and get that bumped up, is it possible to override that using php.ini?

the setup is Drupal using Nginx on a CentOS machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No way.

This is an nginx related setting, PHP is not inside nginx (it is another server, quite certainly a php-fpm daemon), so there is absolutely no way for any PHP manipulation to alter the web server settings.

Comment: But then will it be possible to have a local nginx.conf file in the code, which can be included in the global nginx.conf file and which can override the settings in the global nginx.conf file?

Comment: something like a .htaccess :-), no, but `client_max_body_size` can be set on 3 levels: global, virtualhost, or location. This is something that should be in your nginx virualhost settings. And in nginx this is by definition the job of the http server manager, give him your config.